# Getting the methods of a class

Tags: java, reflection

When using reflection to get some concrete class's methods -- even if I have not explicitly defined any methods of that class -- default superclass (Object) methods (wait, equals, toString, etc...) are returned while others that are otherwise only accessible via reflection (getSimpleName, isAnnotation, isSynthetic, etc...) are not.

Why is this?

Are methods which are only accessible via reflection arbitrarily parsed from output or is something more interesting happening behind the scenes?

How can I apply this principle to my own concrete class so that getMethods() only returns the methods I explicitly define in my class (or arbitrarily choose, but that seems extremely advanced) and not the default methods which are inherited from Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The superclass of all reference types is `Object`. The methods `wait(..)`, `equals(..)`, `toString()` are defined there and those are the ones you get.

The other methods you've listed are from the class `Class` which is the entry point for all reflective operations.

> How can I apply this principle to my own concrete class so that
>   getMethods() only returns the methods I explicitly define in my class
>   (or arbitrarily choose, but that seems extremely advanced) and not the
>   default methods which are inherited from Class?

You can't with `getMethods()`. But you can use [`getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) to get only those methods declared in the class corresponding to the `Class` object it was invoked on.

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared
>   methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object,
>   including public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   methods, **but excluding inherited methods.**